# Where did I go wrong: B-Spline recursion and B-Spline using determinants

Tags: numerical-methods, spline

For $ B^2_1(t) $ with knot values $ t_1 = 1, ..., t_4 = 4 $
Using the determinant method
$ B^d_i(t) = (-1)^{d+1} (t_{i+d+1}-t_i) \frac1D A $

where D is the determinant of 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \ t_i \ ... \ t_1^d+1
\\
...
\\
1 \ t_{i+d+1} \ ... \ t_{i+d+1} ^{d+1}
\end{bmatrix}$ = 12

and A is the determinant of 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \ t_i \ ... \ t_i^d \ g(t_i)
\\
...
\\
1 \ t_{i+d+1} \ ... \ t_{i+d+1}^d \ g(t_{i+d+1})
\end{bmatrix}$ s.t. g(x) is the spline fn $ (t-x)_+^d $

thus by expanding along the last column (ie the column with g(t))
$ A = 2(t-1)_+^2 - 6(t-2)_+^2 + 6(t-3)_+^2 - 2(t-4)_+^2 $

then $ B^2_1(t) = \frac{-1}{4}[2(t-1)_+^2 - 6(t-2)_+^2 + 6(t-3)_+^2 - 2(t-4)_+^2] \\
 = \frac12[(t-4)_+^2 - (t-1)_+^2] + \frac32[(t-2)_+^2 - (t-3)_+^2]$

Then the with the recursion formula 
$ B^d_i(t) = \frac{t-t_i}{t_{i+d} - t_i} B_{i}^{d-1}(t) + \frac{t_{i+d+1}-t}{t_{i+d+1} - t_{i+1}} B_{i+1}^{d-1}(t) $

I get: $ B^2_1(t) = \frac12[(t-1)[(t-3)_+^1 - 2(t-2)_+^1 + (t-1)_+^1] + (t-4)[(t-4)_+^1 - 2(t-3)_+^1 + (t-2)_+^1]] \\
 = \frac12[ - (t-4)_+^2 + (t-1)_+^2] + \frac32[ - (t-2)_+^2 + (t-3)_+^2]$

However my two $ B^2_1(t) $ aren't the same. (note: the signs are different)
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $B$ splines are usually taken to be nonnegative. The easiest way to check nonnegativity is to look at the sign of the coefficient of $(t-t_i)_+^d$ with the smallest $t_i$. This coefficient should be positive.

So, the first formula has the wrong sign. It seems that  when expanding the denominator $A$ along the last column, you did not account for it being the last column (remember $(-1)^{i+j}$ factors in the expansion).

Comment: So for the sign are you saying based on where i'm expanding along its $ (-1)^{r+c} $ ? also does the index start at 0 or 1?

Comment: @swagmasterdelux Yes, that's what I refer to. It does not matter if you start at $0$ or $1$, the parity of $r+c$ is the same. I usually count the number of steps it takes to get to a cell from the top left corner. If it's odd, the sign is $-$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I just checked it with another method (B-spline using divided difference) and it looks like my determinant is indeed wrong